# JMeter - throughput

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to test 5 HTTP requests in a ThreadGroup. I need to define a different throughput rate for each, but cannot put them in separate groups, because I'd like to variate the number of threads for that particular group.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) is what you're looking for.

In regards to "separate groups" - you can set thread number as a property for, the same for all groups, and set this property during JMeter execution via `jmeter.properties` file or `-J` command line argument like:

Set "Number of Threads" in Thread Group to `${__P(virtual.users,)}`

and launch JMeter as:

`jmeter -Jvirtual.users=50 ... ... ...`

Hope this all helps.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but you can use in that way

> cmd.exe /c jmeter.bat --nongui -JforcePerfmonFile=true  --runremote
>   --testfile "performance.jmx" 
>   `--jmeterproperty "perf.properties"`

in file perf.properties set:

> virtual.users=50

and it will used 50 for your players.

Hope this all helps

Answer (score 0):

[Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) should be also a choice.

**Thread Group**

- Throughput Controller2: 98%
- Throughput Controller2: 2%

  - Http Request1
  - Http Request2

When Throughput Controller set percent 2%,
Here are run rate: Http Request1: 2% ,Http Request2: 2%.